# How do I put a small question mark over the Greater than or equals to sign?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have seen people put small question marks over greater than symbols in proofs, however, I'm having trouble doing it over "≥" symbols. Using `\stackrel{?}{≥}` returns an error:

```
 Command \> already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.175 \newcommand{\>}{\stackrel{?}{?}}
?
```

And using `\overset{?}{≥}` gives the wrong symbol:

[image]

How would we type "≥" in latex without returning a question mark?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please post a minimal example, just not an image of an error. You are being told you cannot define `\<`, so find another name for it. In general it is not a good idea to use so short macro names for your own personal macros.

Comment: Try `\newcommand\maybegeq{\stackrel{?}{\geq}}`. With the `amsmath` package, `\overset{?}{\geq}` works as well. I don't think that you can use the greater-equal unicode character directly.

Comment: @gernot I suggest you make that an answer

Answer (score 8):

Use `\geq` instead of `≥` and define the command as

```
\newcommand\maybegeq{\stackrel{?}{\geq}}
```

or as

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\maybegeq{\overset{?}{\geq}}
```

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$x \stackrel{?}{\geq} y$

$x \overset{?}{\geq} y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\stackrel` and `\overset` differ in the way they are spaced. `\stackrel{a}{b}` is a relation no matter what `b` was (as `rel` in the macro name suggests), whereas `\overset{a}{b}` will be treated in the same way as `b` without `\overset`. If you want `\overset{a}{b}` to become a relation, you have to say so explicitly using `\mathrel{\overset{a}{b}}` or `\overset{a}{\mathrel{b}}`.

[image]

Comment: I believe `\overset` is preferred to `\stackrel` (due to better spacing or something).

Comment: @erik It depends on what your aim is. I have added an explanation. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Doing `\newcommand{\>}{\stackrel{?}{≥}}` obviously produces an error, because `\>` is an already defined command.

You could do

```
\renewcommand{\>}{\stackrel{?}{≥}}
```

but it wouldn't help much, because an input like

```
$a \> b$
```

would not print what you'd like to. Even if you load

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(assuming you're saving your file in UTF-8 encoding) wouldn't be sufficient.

You *can* use `≥` as a shorthand for `\geq`, by defining an action for the Unicode character `≥` (and `≤` as well).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{≤}{\leq}
\newunicodechar{≥}{\geq}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\verb|\stackrel|    & \verb|\overset| \\
$a\stackrel{?}{≤}b$ & $a\overset{?}{≤}b$ \\
$a\stackrel{?}{≥}b$ & $a\overset{?}{≥}b$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer `\overset` to `\stackrel`, because it's more general.

About redefining `\>` for this purpose, I wouldn't do it. You can rather do

```
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\overset{?}{#1}}
```

and input

```
$a \?{>} b$
$a \?{≥} b$
$a \?{<} b$
$a \?{≤} b$
```

which is, in my opinion, clearer.

[image]

Comment: Is `\newcommand{\?}{\overset{?}}` in any way preferable?

Comment: @gernot It is essentially equivalent, but less clear. You save a few nanoseconds every time `\?` is expanded.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Ask the Unicode Consortium…